# Units of $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{a}^\dagger$ in discrete vs continuous $k$ and normalization

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, units, dimensional-analysis, commutator

Consider the quantization of the electromagnetic field. In the discrete case, [given in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization_of_the_electromagnetic_field#Quantization_of_EM_field), the operators $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{a}^\dagger$ are dimensionless $$[\hat{a}]=[\hat{a}^\dagger] = 1,$$ which is consistent with the commutation relation $[\hat{a},\hat{a}^\dagger]=\delta_{\vec{k},\vec{k}'}$. This is also consistent with $$ \vec{E} = i\sum_{\vec{k},s}\sqrt{\frac{\hbar\omega}{2V\epsilon_0}}[\vec{e}_s\hat{a}_{\vec{k},s}e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}} + \vec{e}_s\hat{a}_{\vec{k},s}^\dagger e^{-i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}] $$ meaning that $[\vec{E}] = \text{V}/\text{m}$ in SI units.

Now consider the continuous case in which $[\hat{a},\hat{a}^\dagger]=\delta^3(\vec{k}-\vec{k}')$. This commutation relation implies that the units of the creation and annihilation operators are $$ [\hat{a}]=[\hat{a}^\dagger] = \text{distance}^{3/2}. $$ However if I take the limit to $k$ continuous using $$ \lim_{V\to\infty}\frac{1}{V} \sum_\vec{k} \to \int d^3k $$ in the expression of $E$ [given in Wikipedia](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/3de89b53b8f889d788cddcc58e1ecf73c8a4861f) ([in this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization_of_the_electromagnetic_field#Quantization_of_EM_field)) now the units don't match. Also, the volume $V$ does not cancel out so in this limit $E=\infty$. I mean, taking the previous expression for $\vec{E}$ and applying this limit gives $$ \vec{E} = i\sum_{s} \int d^3k \sqrt{\frac{\hbar\omega V}{2\epsilon_0}}[\vec{e}_s\hat{a}_{\vec{k},s}e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}} + \vec{e}_s\hat{a}_{\vec{k},s}^\dagger e^{-i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}] $$ which, obviously, has the same units as before thus being non consistent with the "new units" of the operators.

How are these "units problem" and "infinity problem" solved?

Answer (score 3):

If you write
$$
H = \int \frac{d^3 k}{(2\pi)^3}E({\bf k})  \hat a^\dagger({\bf k})\hat a({\bf k})e^{i{\bf k}\cdot {\bf x}}
$$
then the dimensions $[a]= {\rm L}^{3/2}$ work out as $[k]= {\rm L}^{-1}$

In one dimension with periodic boundary conditions
$$
k= \frac{2\pi  n} {L}
$$
and for quantities that vary smoothly with $k$ we can write
$$
\sum_n \to \int dn = L \int \frac {dk}{2\pi}.
$$

Rather more heuristically we have
$$
\delta(k-k')= \delta\left(\frac {2\pi}{ L}(n-n')\right)= \frac L{2\pi} \delta(n-n')\equiv  \frac L{2\pi}\delta_{nn'}
$$
which is consistent with  $2\pi \delta(k=0) =  L$, which also follows  from setting $k=0$ in
$$
2\pi \delta(k)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  e^{ikx}dx.
$$
Thus the the factors of the length $L$'s  are also consistent.

In the expression for $H$ we have absorbed the  factor $L^3$ in front of the integral into the $a$'s.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know which would be the "normalization factor" or whatever that multiplies $E$ in order to have the correct units?

Comment: It should already be correct:  If $E(k)$ is in Joules then the eigenvalue  of the eigenstate $|k\rangle =\hat a^\dagger(k) |0\rangle$ of  $H$ is $E(k)$ and is in Joules.

Comment: I have updated my question to better illustrate my point.